# Stop Windows 7 poweroff on critical error

Tags: windows-7, windows, power-management

How do I stop Windows 7 from powering off in the even in the event of a critical system error (or whatever error causes that)?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Control Panel, click on System and Security, click on System, and choose "Advanced system settings" on the left panel. Click "settings" under "Startup and recovery", then uncheck "Automatically restart" under "System failure".